# Is it possible to Pivot this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

My query

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.tblacc_cv.cv_docno, 
                dbo.tblacc_cv.cv_docdate, 
                dbo.tblacc_cv.cv_suppliername, 
                dbo.tblacc_cv.cv_extdocno, 
                dbo.tblacc_chartaccount.coa_cvtype AS cvtype, 
                dbo.tblacc_glentry.gl_accountid, 
                ( CASE 
                    WHEN dbo.tblacc_glentry.gl_accountid = '201001' THEN Sum( 
                    dbo.tblacc_glentry.gl_credit) 
                    ELSE NULL 
                  END )                            AS AP, 
                ( CASE 
                    WHEN dbo.tblacc_glentry.gl_accountid = '208000' THEN Sum( 
                    dbo.tblacc_glentry.gl_amount) 
                    ELSE NULL 
                  END )                            AS EWT, 
                ( CASE 
                    WHEN dbo.tblacc_glentry.gl_accountid = '616000' 
                         AND dbo.tblacc_chartaccount.coa_cvtype = 'S' THEN Sum( 
                    dbo.tblacc_glentry.gl_debit) 
                    ELSE NULL 
                  END )                            AS FABpur, 
                ( CASE 
                    WHEN dbo.tblacc_glentry.gl_accountid = '603000' 
                         AND dbo.tblacc_chartaccount.coa_cvtype = 'S' THEN Sum( 
                    dbo.tblacc_glentry.gl_debit) 
                    ELSE NULL 
                  END )                            AS FABcre, 
                ( CASE 
                    WHEN dbo.tblacc_glentry.gl_accountid = '602000' 
                         AND dbo.tblacc_chartaccount.coa_cvtype = 'S' THEN Sum( 
                    dbo.tblacc_glentry.gl_debit) 
                    ELSE NULL 
                  END )                            AS RawMat, 
                ( CASE 
                    WHEN dbo.tblacc_glentry.gl_accountid = '601003' 
                         AND dbo.tblacc_chartaccount.coa_cvtype = 'S' THEN Sum( 
                    dbo.tblacc_glentry.gl_debit) 
                    ELSE NULL 
                  END )                            AS PurCre, 
                ( CASE 
                    WHEN dbo.tblacc_glentry.gl_accountid NOT IN ( 
                         '201001', '208000', '616000', '603000', 
                         '602000', '601003' ) THEN 
                    dbo.tblacc_glentry.gl_accountname 
                    ELSE NULL 
                  END )                            AS GL_AccountName, 
                ( CASE 
                    WHEN dbo.tblacc_glentry.gl_accountid NOT IN ( 
                         '616000', '603000', '602000', '601003' 
                              ) 
                         AND dbo.tblacc_chartaccount.coa_cvtype = 'M' THEN Sum( 
                    dbo.tblacc_glentry.gl_debit) 
                    ELSE NULL 
                  END )                            AS MOdr, 
                ( CASE 
                    WHEN dbo.tblacc_glentry.gl_accountid NOT IN ( 
                         '616000', '603000', '602000', '601003' 
                              ) 
                         AND dbo.tblacc_chartaccount.coa_cvtype = 'F' THEN Sum( 
                    dbo.tblacc_glentry.gl_debit) 
                    ELSE NULL 
                  END )                            AS FDR, 
                ( CASE 
                    WHEN dbo.tblacc_glentry.gl_accountid NOT IN ( 
                         '201001', '208000', '616000', '603000', 
                         '602000', '601003' ) 
                         AND dbo.tblacc_chartaccount.coa_cvtype = 'S' THEN Sum( 
                    dbo.tblacc_glentry.gl_debit) 
                    ELSE NULL 
                  END )                            AS SunDR, 
                ( CASE 
                    WHEN dbo.tblacc_glentry.gl_accountid NOT IN ( 
                         '201001', '208000', '616000', '603000', 
                         '602000', '601003' ) 
                         AND dbo.tblacc_chartaccount.coa_cvtype = 'S' THEN Sum( 
                    dbo.tblacc_glentry.gl_credit) 
                    ELSE NULL 
                  END )                            AS SunCR 
FROM   dbo.tblacc_glentry 
       INNER JOIN dbo.tblacc_apv 
               ON dbo.tblacc_glentry.gl_docno = dbo.tblacc_apv.apv_docno 
       INNER JOIN dbo.tblacc_cv 
                  INNER JOIN dbo.tblacc_cvdetail 
                          ON dbo.tblacc_cv.cv_docno = 
                             dbo.tblacc_cvdetail.cvd_cv_docno 
               ON dbo.tblacc_apv.apv_docno = dbo.tblacc_cvdetail.cvd_refdocno 
       INNER JOIN dbo.tblacc_chartaccount 
               ON dbo.tblacc_glentry.gl_accountid = 
                  dbo.tblacc_chartaccount.coa_account_id 
WHERE  ( dbo.tblacc_cv.cv_docdate BETWEEN 
         '01/01/2018 00:00:00' AND '1/30/2018 23:59:59' ) 
GROUP  BY dbo.tblacc_cv.cv_docno, 
          dbo.tblacc_cv.cv_docdate, 
          dbo.tblacc_cv.cv_suppliername, 
          dbo.tblacc_glentry.gl_accountname, 
          dbo.tblacc_cv.cv_extdocno, 
          dbo.tblacc_chartaccount.coa_cvtype, 
          dbo.tblacc_glentry.gl_accountid, 
          dbo.tblacc_glentry.gl_credit, 
          dbo.tblacc_glentry.gl_amount, 
          dbo.tblacc_glentry.gl_debit 
ORDER  BY dbo.tblacc_cv.cv_docdate ASC
```

Sample Output

[image: Sample Output]

Desired Ouput

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: The output from *any* query can be pivoted.

Comment: Based on your output, you don't need a pivot... you just need to aggregate those columns to remove the `NULL`, which would also pick a value for the other columns where the other rows aren't null

Comment: you have some fields that are not unique, so your pivot will not be able to group the columns together.. like `cvtype` and `glaccount_id`

Comment: Also, for some fields, it is not obvious what your criterion for making a particular selection is. Example: For field `CVType` in your output, is the criterion for selection the first value, or does the 'M' value always get displayed? Also, are there more values, and, if so, what is the general rule for making the selection? (Edit - Noted that there is also a possible 'F' value according to your query.)

Comment: What I mostly see in other posts is a `SUM(CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END)`, instead of the `CASE WHEN .... THEN SUM(...) ELSE null END` seen in this query.  It's not the same!    As for why you got 3 lines, that's because it also groups on `coa_cvtype` & `gl_accountid`, so remove those from the GROUP BY, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output is not an example of a PIVOT.

Lacking a detailed explanation of your logic, I can tell you that you can get your desired output by GROUPing BY the first four columns, and applying MAX() to all the others.  (Except `cvtype` which would be a MIN).

Comment: Or, possibly, by applying SUM() to the numeric columns. We don't know if there are multiple rows sometimes for each column that need to be consolidated. As you said, insufficient information so far.

Comment: @LaughingVergil Yes, lacking additional explanation, we don't know a lot of things.  There are numerous ways to get the desired result from the sample data; this is only one way.